# How to set an integer session when setting the value of c:set [JSTL]

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have this code

```
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value='<%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>' />
                    <c:if test="${salary == 121}">
                        <a href="create-news-item">Create News Item</a>
                        <br />
                    </c:if>
```

When I change the value of salary to 121 it works. But when I called the value then set it as a value of salary the link doesnt show... How to correclty called the session as an integer value?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix *scriptlets* and EL. This makes no sense. Your *scriptlet* approach would only implicitly convert it to `String` via `Object#toString()` call as done in `out.print(Object)` method which is called by `<%= %>`.

In this particular case, you can just use

```
<c:if test="${theName == 121}">
    <a href="create-news-item">Create News Item</a>
    <br />
</c:if>
```

EL searches by default for the attributes in page, request, session and application scopes already.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)